# javascript countdown timer set to display from start date to end date

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

Trying to convert our existing countdown timer which counts from 7 days. Need countdown to go display start date to end date in DD HH MM.

```
var count = {time: new Date('Nov 12, 2019 10:00:00').getTime() };
var timeLeft = count.time - Date.now();


// displays countdown of DD HH MM correctly.
var count = { time: 7000 * 60 * 60 * 24};

function setTime() {
  // var timeLeft = count.time;

  var days = Math.floor(timeLeft / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  timeLeft -= days * 1000;

  var hours = Math.floor((timeLeft % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  timeLeft -= hours * 60 * 60;

  var minutes = Math.floor((timeLeft % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  timeLeft -= minutes * 60;

  days = ("0" + days).slice(-2);
  hours = ("0" + hours).slice(-2);
  minutes = ("0" + minutes).slice(-2);

  document.getElementById("cDay").innerHTML = days;
  document.getElementById("cHour").innerHTML = hours;
  document.getElementById("cMin").innerHTML = minutes;

}
```

Count starts correctly, but then goes into chaos, including negatives.
Show countdown timer based on specific start date+time and end date+time.

To clarify, my question is how do I make this .js calculate the countdown from an actual date+time (with the option to only display a span of time... ie: event is Nov 24-31).

We've tried to replace the "var count = { time: 7000 * 60 * 60 * 24};" to "var count = {time: new Date('Nov 24, 2019 10:00:00').getTime() };" but this blows up the countdown. I need an accurate display of Day : Hour : Minute.

Comment: Hi @LK1037, please share with us what you have tried to fix this problem. Also your post does not actually ask a question. I would suggest reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and rephrasing your question accordingly.

Comment: To clarify, my question is how do I make this .js calculate the countdown from an actual date+time (with the option to only display a span of time... ie: event is Nov 24-31). We've tried to replace the "var count = { time: 7000 * 60 * 60 * 24};" to "var count = {time: new Date('Nov 24, 2019 10:00:00').getTime() };" but this blows up the countdown. I need an accurate display of Day : Hour : Minute.

Comment: Thats helpful. I would add the information from your last commen to your question. So that people see this when reading the question.

Comment: Right on. Added. Thanks.